# How to fix system Lag and Stuttering on Ubuntu 22.04 & NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, performance

I have been trying to diagnose the cause of lagging, stuttering videos and poor video call performance for quite some time now.

In the past, everything worked smoothly. I can't recall when it started to lag, and therefore I can't determine the exact (if there even exists a single cause) critical update.

The machine is core i7, 32GB RAM, NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti.

OS is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, kernel is 6.2.1-060201-generic

Below is the graphics card driver info:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.89.02    Driver Version: 525.89.02    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   32C    P8     4W / 260W |     62MiB / 11264MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2120      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 61MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this is the example of current htop optput. Right now, when I am typing, there is also a lag - there is a delay between pressing a keyboard and the letter appearance on screen.
[image]

I would appreciate any suggestion about how to fix the issue(s) that are causing lagging.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my i7/8 Go of RAM 2 days a ago and yesterday I noticed some lagging and stuttering that increased overtime. I didn't really try with video, but even when just scrolling a webpage, some of it manifested itself very annoyingly.  

I just switched to Ubuntu with Wayland on the dropdown menu in the log screen to try it. And to my surprise, the problem has just gone and Ubuntu is just so smooth.  

I'm writing this just 30 minutes or so after making the switch, so I'm not sure yet if this is the way to go. I'll try to keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

I use MSI Katana GF66, Since I have upgraded my system to 64GB RAM and 1.5TB NVME SSD, and installed Ubuntu 22.04, I was facing lag while connected to a 75hz monitor via HDMI also very laggy display,

I have tried all solutions but ended up using this which works as the driver compatibility with GeForce 3060 Mobile.

The only solution i found that I have switched to Integrated Graphics

sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx nvidia-prime (xxx  is the your version )
sudo prime-select intel

prime-select query
It should return intel .